Как с помощью REST API Битрикс24, получить список контактов, у которых сегодня или завтра День рождения, без учета года рождения?
Делаю такой запрос:
let payload = {
    cmd: {
      // Получаем список контактов
      contacts: {
        method: 'crm.contact.list',
        params: {
          filter: {
            "%BIRTHDATE": '-01-01',
          },
          select: ["ID", "NAME", "BIRTHDATE"]
        }
      },
    }
  };

Но получаю:
"contacts": [
      {
        "ID": "882",
        "NAME": "Валентина",
        "BIRTHDATE": "2024-06-17T03:00:00+03:00"
      },
]

"BIRTHDATE": "2024-06-17T03:00:00+03:00" - дата не 01.01 а 17.06
Вопрос: Как правильно сделать запрос, чтобы получить контакты с нужной датой рождения, без учета года.
